# Resource endpoint on GraphDB

Tags: rdf, graphdb

I am trying to query a resource from GraphDB.
I have created a Repository named say theOnto. In the graphDB workbench, if I select the Repo from the dropdown and then query a resource, say http://localhost:7200/resource/qLinkage/Program, then it works fine. This works because some cookie is set for the repository name. But I want to hit the same resource url and and get the required data without setting the cookie.

This is possible in many publicly available GraphDBs (e.g. http://dbpedia.org/resource/Database)

This must be possible with some setting on GraphDB server. There must be some way to specify default repository, if none specified. Can anyone provide some pointers about achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the REST Endpoint first -

http://localhost:7200/resource?uri=http://your.uri.com/here

Swap http://your.uri.com/here for your full qLinkage URI.

I would also double check that the qLinkage ontology is loaded into the repository and that qLinkage is the correct namespace prefix that GraphDB is using. If GraphDB has chosen to use ql as its namespace prefix then it will not resolve correctly.

You can also set the default repository in Set-up -> Repositories and then use the pin icon. GraphDB 8+.